# Can only view my own information in the Title field of Group Members

Tags: community, chatter-groups

I have a Salesforce community that groups are being used in. Some of the groups are shared between accounts and the users have nothing in common except the group. The problem I have is that in the view the Title only shows up for yourself, even though all users have a title. I can't change the layout because Salesforce doesn't let you. I can't use share records because SF doesn't let you share with standard community users. I tried setting user to public read/write but they still couldn't see the other user Titles. Any idea how to see all user titles?
[image]